# How can I strip out part of a filename in camel XML route

Tags: regex, apache-camel

I have a camel route defined in XML which picks up files in the format AB1234-20141113.txt and moves them to the ftp server. I need to rename the files in the route stripping out the date part between - and .txt so that the file on the ftp server is AB1234.txt.

As you can see from the example route definition below I have used the File Expression language in the from uri to add to the filename when moving it on the local machine after succeeding or failing but I can't see any easy way to apply a regex or substring transform using it in the ftp uri.

```
<route id="outboundoFtpPoller">
    <from uri="file:/generatedFiles?move=done/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}&amp;moveFailed=failed/${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}"/>
    <to uri="ftp:{{ftp.server}}{{ftp.subdirectory}}/outbox/<what goes here?>" />
</route>
```

Any suggestions of what I can put in the  section to achieve what I am trying to do would be welcome or any suggestions of how I can achieve it in a slightly different way but it must be using camel and the route definition has to remain in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this processor which sets the fileName using a regex before sending the file to the ftp producer

```
<route id="outboundoFtpPoller">
    <from uri="file:/generatedFiles?move=done/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}&amp;moveFailed=failed/${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}"/>
    <bean id="myProcessor" class="mypackage.MyProcessor"/>
    <to uri="ftp:{{ftp.server}}{{ftp.subdirectory}}/outbox/<what goes here?>" />
</route>
```

where my processor is

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String fileName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY, String.class).replaceAll("-\\d+", "");
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,fileName);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Without using a processor try adding this

```
  <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
            <simple>${in.header.CamelFileName.replaceAll("-\d+","")}</simple>
        </setHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks Itsallas I was coming to the conclusion that this might be the only way to do it, however I was hoping to be able to do it inline with a regex or script somehow so that I wouldn't need to create or define a new bean instance every time I had a different filename format or rename requirement but your solution will definitely achieve what I need.